# how to disable special characters text field in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

can anyone help me in this issue.

I want to avoid special characters(!@#$%^&*()) in text field.

Actually I have added javascript code for this.
now I cant enter the spl characters. it's working perfect. 
But the problem is, the data is not going to be inserted after submitted.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function alpha(e) {
    var k;
    document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}  
    </script>

'customCode' => '<input type="text" onkeypress="return alpha(event)">',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the name of textfield in customCode. Your customCode should be like:

> 'customCode' => '< input type="text" onkeypress="return alpha(event)" name="your-textbox-name">',